# HTML image behind object

Tags: html

i am new in html and php so i want your help,
I want to add an image behind some objects (2 textbox, one link, one submit button) on html. How can i do that? take example the facebook the blue bar where over it is the login items..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the background-image clause in CSS

Examples here
http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlbackground.php

Just add a "div" and insert what you want inside him.
Then set it a width and a height to fit your background image.

Comment: Thanks guys it works

<html>
<table height="70" width="500"
 background="http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/background.jpg" >
<tr><td><input type="text" name="txt"></td></tr>
</table>
</html>

is the answer, thanks to all.

Comment: @vsikariam: you should realy do this with css if you are serious about becoming a descent web developer/designer. The quick and dirty code would then be: `<html><table style="width:500px; height:70px; background-image: url('tizag.com/pics/htmlT/background.jpg');"><tr><td><input type="text" name="txt"></td></tr></table></html>`. This will work, but even better would be to read up on css and use an external stylesheet to style all of you html code. It will make things a lot easyer as you start developing larger sites.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify an image as background for the element which contains your objects. I guess this will be a div. All about background-images can be found via google or here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to set the background color, or as other people have mentioned, a background image.

Assuming your elements are contained in a `<div id="my-background">` element, the following style will apply a blue background to the div:

`#my-background { background-color:#0000FF }`

You may want to read up on CSS.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <table background="image.png" width=100%>
> <tr>
> <td>
> <font color="white">Email</font><br>
> <input type="text" name = "email" size="25"><br>
> </td>
> <td>
> <font color="white">Password</font><br>
> <input type="password" name = "password" size="25">
> <input type = "Submit" value = "Log in" height='5'><br>
> </td>
> </tr>
> </table>
> ```

but the texbox is not looks nice... there is huge space between one...